# CSS Grid Errors (using Grid Polyfill)

Tags: css, html, grid

I use the CSS Grid Polyfill from https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-grid-polyfill

I try to use the following HTML

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px 300px; grid-template-rows: 200px 400px; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 600px; left: 90px; top: 122px">
    <button style="position: absolute; width: 134px; height: 51px; grid-column: 2; grid-row: 1; left: 21px; top: 34px" horizontal-alignment="Left" vertical-alignment="Top">Button</button>
    <button style="position: absolute; width: 134px; height: 51px; grid-column: 2; grid-row: 2; left: 134px; top: 303px" horizontal-alignment="Left" vertical-alignment="Top">Button</button>
</div>
```

But I get the following errors:

Invalid Declaration: grid-column/row: attr(stryle) / attr(style) (invalid token)

and this one:

INVALID DECLARATION: grid-template-rows/columns: attr(style) (unrecognized track breadth)

To say, I use the Grid in a Polymer component!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not providing enough values to `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`, so technically you only have one column and one row. When defining `grid-templates`, you need to provide a value for each line getting drawn, which defines the grid (think Rules in photoshop). Currently, you are passing only two attributes, `200px` and `300px`. The Grid interprets this as:

- Line 1: 200px from left edge.
- Line 2: 300px from Line 1.

([visual example of your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12oi3.png))

Because only two grid lines are defined in your `grid-template-column/row`, only one "grid area" exists, the space in-between Line 1 and Line 2. So the CSS on your buttons is looking for `grid-column/row-2`, which doesn't exist, causing the Grid to fail.

In order to solve this, you'll need to define more lines for the columns and rows. Update your templates to include a zero-distance column/row like this:

```
grid-template-columns: 0px 200px 300px;
grid-template-rows: 0px 200px 400px;
```

This will draw three grid lines, which creates two grid areas. The `grid-column: 2;` CSS on your button will now place it in the second column, which now exists.

([visual example of updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSzGX.png))

> As an additional note, I would *not* recommend combining `position:
>   absolute;` with the CSS Grid Spec (it overrides all the functionality
>   that Grid provides).